# Como instalar o driver PDO_PGSQL no ubuntu?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, ubuntu

Já tenho instalado o PHP 7, Apache 2 e Postgresql 9.5.

Já habilitei a extensão no `php.ini` porém não funciona.

No Windows basta habilitar essa extensão no `php.ini` que já funciona porém aqui no Ubuntu não foi suficiente.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que devo fazer para resolver.

Comment: Informar a versão do Ubuntu pode ajudar

Comment: Me desculpe, a versão é 16.04 LTS

Comment: sudo systemctl restart apache2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Em sistemas Linux a instalação de extensões é um pouco diferente. As extensões não estão ali por padrão, mas podemos instalar com o `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt install php-pgsql
```

Dependendo da sua versão do Ubuntu/PHP, execute o seguinte

```
sudo apt install php5-pgsql
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

No Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) LTS, o commando de instalação é:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql
```